# Split a string (on whitespace or punctuation) to get all numbers

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a string

```
Mystring = "123 456 789, 234, 999|567 888[222"
```

I want to split this string for `" "` `","` `"|"`, and `"["` to get all the numbers in a list

Expected Output:-

```
List = ["123","456","789","234","999",567","888","222"]
```

I'm using following piece of code

```
Final_List = re.findall("(\d+?)[ ,|\]]",Mystring)
```

Actual Output:

```
["123","456","789",234","999",567"]
```

How can i get all the numbers here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of splitting the string, why not just get the numbers directly:

```
>>> import re
>>> Mystring = "123 456 789, 234, 999|567 888[222"
>>> re.findall('\d+', Mystring)
['123', '456', '789', '234', '999', '567', '888', '222']
>>>
```

`\d+` has Python match one or more digits (a number).

Comment: [0-9]+ restricts it to Arabic numerals

Comment: Thanks :-) Another question, How can i use ']' or '[' inside square brackets [] to delimit it?

Comment: @Bad_Coder - `[` can go inside a character set just fine: `[[]`.  For `]`, you will need to escape it: `[\]]`.

Comment: @Bad_Coder: `r'[,|\[\]]'` ; r is for raw string, use it to keep your regexes uncluttered by a forest of backslashes. Read the [Python re doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
tbl = string.maketrans(',|[',"   ")

print(Mystring.translate(tbl)).split()
['123', '456', '789', '234', '999', '567', '888', '222']


In [29]: import string

In [30]: %%timeit
   ....: tbl = string.maketrans(',|[',"   ")
   ....: (Mystring.translate(tbl)).split()
   ....: 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 762 ns per loop

In [31]: import re

In [32]: timeit re.findall('\d+', Mystring)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.99 µs per loop
```

Comment: translate is pretty efficient